# Integrating Apache Jena to Oracle 12c Error: Invalid common user or role name

Tags: java, oracle, jena, oracle12c

I am new to oracle and Jena both. For my project I am convert Json data to RDF using Apache Jena successfully. I downloaded the latest version of Oracle ie 12c as it supports storage of RDF data and since it has Jena Adapter Support.

I followed all the steps to set up Jena Adapter given [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11828/sem_jena.htm#DAIBDFGG) in section 7.1. After point 9 there it says to enable queries to perform [section 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/sem_jena.htm#RDFRM242). Since I am new to Oracle I have set it up but now when I am creating a user I get error

```
CREATE USER rdfusr IDENTIFIED BY rdfusr DEFAULT TABLESPACE rdf_users
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

How to resolve this? Are there any blog/links on how to integrate Jena to Oracle 12c?

Comment: I was going to suggest you use the [12c version of the instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/sem_jena.htm#CBBFCJAH), but those aren't clear on that distinction either, and don't refer to containers.

Comment: I believe its not upated as per 12c